# Flutter SDK error: Error: Getter not found: 'isLink'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the following error in the SDK files after trying to compile my project. I redownloaded and rebuilt the entire tools but I still get it.

```
           Compiler message:                                            
[   +1 ms] ../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3627:45: Error: Getter not found: 'isLink'.
[        ]   bool get isLink => _hasFlag(SemanticsFlag.isLink);         
[        ]                                             ^^^^^^           
[        ] ../../development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/semantics/semantics.dart:3629:28: Error: Getter not found: 'isLink'.
[        ]     _setFlag(SemanticsFlag.isLink, value);                   
[        ]                            ^^^^^^                            
[  +96 ms] Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
[        ] Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null             
build failed.
```

It looks like something in the SDK is wrong. How can this be possible?

I'm running like this:

```
flutter --local-engine-src-path ../engine/src --local-engine=host_debug_unopt run
```

Answer (score 0):

`flutter upgrade --force` Did the job for me